When to disable Nagle's algorithm for TcpClient?
From docs:

When NoDelay is false, a TcpClient does not send a packet over the
network until it has collected a significant amount of outgoing data.
Because of the amount of overhead in a TCP segment, sending small
amounts of data is inefficient. However, situations do exist where you
need to send very small amounts of data or expect immediate responses
from each packet you send. Your decision should weigh the relative
importance of network efficiency versus application requirements.


How many bytes qualify as small amounts of data in this case?

From my understanding, if you have a NetworkStream that writes to a TCP stream from TcpClient once per request (i.e. not in a loop or chunking manner) followed by flushing immediately then NoDelay doesn't matter, based of John Nagle response. What is the delay in DotNet when NoDelay is not set for a write?

That still irks me. The real problem is not tinygram prevention. It's
ACK delays, and that stupid fixed timer. They both went into TCP
around the same time, but independently. I did tinygram prevention
(the Nagle algorithm) and Berkeley did delayed ACKs, both in the early
1980s. The combination of the two is awful. Unfortunately by the time
I found about delayed ACKs, I had changed jobs, was out of networking,
and doing a product for Autodesk on non-networked PCs. Delayed ACKs
are a win only in certain circumstances - mostly character echo for
Telnet. (When Berkeley installed delayed ACKs, they were doing a lot
of Telnet from terminal concentrators in student terminal rooms to
host VAX machines doing the work. For that particular situation, it
made sense.) The delayed ACK timer is scaled to expected human
response time. A delayed ACK is a bet that the other end will reply to
what you just sent almost immediately. Except for some RPC protocols,
this is unlikely. So the ACK delay mechanism loses the bet, over and
over, delaying the ACK, waiting for a packet on which the ACK can be
piggybacked, not getting it, and then sending the ACK, delayed.
There's nothing in TCP to automatically turn this off. However, Linux
(and I think Windows) now have a TCP_QUICKACK socket option. Turn that
on unless you have a very unusual application.
Turning on TCP_NODELAY has similar effects, but can make throughput
worse for small writes. If you write a loop which sends just a few
bytes (worst case, one byte) to a socket with "write()", and the Nagle
algorithm is disabled with TCP_NODELAY, each write becomes one IP
packet. This increases traffic by a factor of 40, with IP and TCP
headers for each payload. Tinygram prevention won't let you send a
second packet if you have one in flight, unless you have enough data
to fill the maximum sized packet. It accumulates bytes for one round
trip time, then sends everything in the queue. That's almost always
what you want. If you have TCP_NODELAY set, you need to be much more
aware of buffering and flushing issues.
None of this matters for bulk one-way transfers, which is most HTTP
today. (I've never looked at the impact of this on the SSL handshake,
where it might matter.)
Short version: set TCP_QUICKACK. If you find a case where that makes
things worse, let me know.
John Nagle


While NoDelay is sent on the sender side, what other TCP-related optimizations can be done on a receiver to receive small size data (500 bytes - 2 KB) as efficient as possible in a low-latency environment?



lets say you have a challenge Response type of communikation, you send Hello And get who are you, you sned me and the response is which password has me and so on, that is a sample of short messages that can not be collected to you have no or less ovehead of zje 1200 bytes, but i doubt you will have much use to collect data, as you have to ectract the portion again


It comes down to whether the data is larger than the MTU (the TCP send packet size). If the data is more than that (or if there are no unacknowledged sent packets) then it will be sent immediately, otherwise it's buffered until the MSS is reached. The MSS is commonly 1500 bytes, taking off the overheads which is 40 bytes gets you an MTU of 1460 bytes.

No this is incorrect. NetworkStream.Flush does nothing at all:

The Flush method implements the Stream.Flush method; however, because NetworkStream is not buffered, it has no effect on network streams. Calling the Flush method does not throw an exception.

So it makes no difference if you call it. Nagles' alogorithm will be used unless disabled using TCP_NODELAY.

None really except the usual:

Use pre-created pooled buffers.
Use async code.
Hand off reading to another thread or the thread-pool, rather than on the UI thread, which requires extra synchronization and marshalling.



As to your quote: it's very possible that TCP_QUICKACK might be a better idea than TCP_NODELAY, but I suggest you test it against your typical usage.

Thanks for the detailed response. I also found a great youtube video detailing what you mention https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adDC5T-RzR4
